# How does tracking work?

Tags: network, anonymity, tracking, deanonymization

Imagine I create a machine (laptop maybe) in which I don't use a browser, I just perfom an attack and use macchanger, VPN or maybe proxychains. And I'm on an open wifi network. The question is how do they track me? How tracking works?

I also want to know if I changed my network adapter on the laptop, is still there any unique identifying information that could leak from my laptop? If yes, then what type of information?

Comment: There are many possible ways that you can be tracked, mostly because in the attack you describe, there are many complex parts working together and any one of them might be misconfigured or faulty. You also don't describe what you mean by 'tracked'. Can you expand on that? Do you mean tracking the network traffic to your physical location? Do you mean attributing the attack to you personally?

Comment: Not sure about this SE site, but It might be too broad, as there's no clear answer. Probably explaining why there was a downvote.

Comment: Question is simple! Here Tracking  means who ever perform an attack, how they got to know the person or machine behind that attack,  How it works?

Comment: Question is simple to you. Tracking person and tracking a machine are two very, very different things and are performed in very different ways. See my answer. I had no idea what machine was used, but I traced the person. You need to refine this question.

Comment: For instance, if you use a VPN, law enforcement could simply ask the VPN provider for your account info. But you will come back saying, what if I somehow use a fake account on the VPN, etc, etc. Each piece to the puzzle has its own method, and you are asking for the full spectrum of options. That makes this too broad.

Answer (score 3):

I run honeypots, and I once caught a hacker because he used his full legal name as a password, and he used the same username he used for an online dating profile. With those two pieces of data, I was able to go so far as to get his phone number at his place of work.

Sometimes, technology doesn't unmask you, but the way you attack does.